# Not able to login after changing template file in backend

Tags: typo3

I wanted to add Google Analytics tracking code so I followed a tutorial on how to include its code inside some template file in backend. I am not sure how the file was called, template-something I believe. 
At the end in editor I have placed the following code and after backend refresh I got fatal error.

```
 page.wrap (   
    // tracking code 
 )
```

How can I fix this issue? I have tried searching database for "googletagmanager", I have found code in `sys_template` and `cache_pages`, I have cleaned up my part but everthing is the same. I can also see there are some results in `cache_hash` and `sys_history`, but there are blobs inside and I can't find a way to search inside them? Is it safe to empty cache_hash table?

EDIT: I have manually edited blobs and uploaded cleaned from my insert, I have deleted rows fromo `cache_hash`, no change

It seems that problems is in `temp_CACHED_ps20c1_ext_localconf` file

Answer (score 0):

**`temp_CACHED_ps20c1_ext_localconf.php` means a pre 6.0 version. So you need to update!**

That file is a cache for the configuration. You should delete all files like `typo3conf/temp_*`.

So you have not specified your exact code, I only can guess.

The usual inclusion of google tracking starts with an include of javascript from google in the header (`page.headerData. ....`).
But even then you need to be careful if you include javascript in a multiline value. You start the multiline value with a `(` after the initial property. This multiline will end on a line which starts with a `)` (after whitespace). If your javascript includes such a line your typoscript gets confused. Such an error could be found in the TSOB or Template analyzer.

Comment: I have tried renaming those files to filename__old  but they keep regenerating :/ Analytics can wait, I need to fix fatal errors first..

Comment: of cause they are generated immediately as they are used to compute the FE output. (as they are generated anew you can delete them). you might use the last one to analyze where which error occurs. then you should correct the error in the BE (backand login should be available), then delete the complete caches (and also these files) again.